# C# System.Diagnostics.Process: how to exit a process if it takes more than, say, 10 seconds?

Tags: c#, process, timing

I tried the following code:

```
p = StartProcess("some_process.exe");
DateTime startTime = DateTime.Now;
p.Start();
while (!p.HasExited)
{
    executeTime = (DateTime.Now - startTime).Milliseconds;

    if (executeTime > 10000) // 10 seconds
    {
       Console.Write("Test \"" + inputTest + "\" failed: takes more than 10 seconds");
       break;
    }
}
```

but it doesn't work.

Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could use the [WaitForExit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty0d8k56.aspx) method:

```
if (!p.WaitForExit((int)TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10).TotalMilliseconds))
{
    // timeout exceeded while waiting for the process to exit
}
```

Comment: I love WaitForExit method! I was using it before but I didn't know it had such a wonderful overload. I thing though. It requires an int value as a parameter so we have to cast TotalMilliseconds value to int.

Comment: I should look at overloads more, this is awesome :)

Comment: @Alex, yeap good remark about the Int32 parameter. A cast is needed. I've updated my post to reflect this.

Answer (score 2):

The `WaitForExit` answer is better, because it blocks, but the reason your code doesn't work is because you want `TimeSpan.TotalMilliseconds` rather than `TimeSpan.Milliseconds`. `Milliseconds` gives you something in the range [-999,999]: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.milliseconds.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Call the [`Kill`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.kill.aspx) method on the process variable (p in you example), this will stop the process.

**Note**: The loop in your example is very CPU intensive. You should use the [`WaitForExit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fb4aw7b8.aspx) call to wait 10 seconds (as Darin Dimitrov suggests).